# Cloud Firestore: Update fields in nested objects with dynamic key

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

following the official documentation of firestore :

```
{
    name: "Frank",
    favorites: { food: "Pizza", color: "Blue", subject: "recess" },
    age: 12
}

// To update favorite color:
db.collection("users").doc("frank").update({
    "favorites.color": "Red"
})
```

I would like to use a dynamic key instead of color.

```
db.collection("users").doc("frank").update({
    "favorites[" + KEY + "].color": true
});
```

this is of course not possible and will throw an error.

I've been trying to do this :

```
db.collection("users").doc("frank").update({
    favorites: {
        [key]: {
            color": true
        }
    }
});
```

It is actually updating with the right key but unfortunately, it is overwriting the other keys (they are being deleted).

Answer (score 116, accepted):

I found the solution inspired by a firebase solution (replacing "/" by ".").

```
var usersUpdate = {};
usersUpdate[`favorites.${key}.color`] = true;

db.collection("users").doc("frank").update(usersUpdate);
```

Comment: Related doc -> https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data?authuser=0#update_fields_in_nested_objects

Comment: I'm wondering if that actually works. I would expect it to overwrite the current value of `usersUpdate` with the new one with a single value, namely `{favorites {KEY: {color: true}}}`.If what you say is correct, then there would be no way to actually update `usersUpdate` to a completely new value.

Comment: more briefly, @Georg Hackenberg points out this solution:
`db.collection('users').doc('frank').update({ [\`favorites.${key}.color\`] = true })`

Comment: Why is it invalid? You can use backticks in es6. This solution still work, it is really similar to the answer below. https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/01/ES6-Template-Strings

Comment: This solution is wrong as this will create a new field usersUpdate of type map with child favorites.${key}.color : true - if key=1234 then usersUpdate field will look like ```usersUpdate                                                                           
            {                                                        
                favorites.1234.color : true                                       
            }                                                                                   
   ```

Comment: I don't understand why you're saying it's wrong. The is the intended purpose is to have a key such as "favorites.1234.color", at least it was the way to do it at that time to achieve something similar than Firebase.

Comment: For me it worked. What is weird is that it highlight the entire map even I'm updating only one field of only one value of map

Comment: this doesn't work anymore with the new API

Answer (score 75):

This solution worked for me:

```
db.collection('users').doc('frank').update({
  [`favorites.${key}.color`]: true
});
```

Comment: Correct solution.

Comment: db.collection('users').doc('frank').update({
  [` favorites.${key}.color `]: true
})

Comment: This solution is correct. Also alternate solution : ```db.collection('users').doc('frank').update({ [`favorites.${key}.color `]: true })```  and also be careful enough to avoid blank spaces inside [``] section i.e you would end up doing wrong if you include blank space ```db.collection('users').doc('frank').update({ [` favorites.${key}.color `]: true }```

Comment: doesn't make any nested stuff though :/ just update

Comment: Note for lurkers: This works for update, but for set it saves as a single prop with dot in it's name, not as a nested property.

Comment: doesnt work with new API

Answer (score 33):

Just a note about a potential pitfall:  After discovering that you can update nested fields using a dot syntax, I tried using `set()` the same way, since I needed it to work whether the object already exists or not:

```js
var updateObj = {['some.nested.property']: 9000};
docRef.set(updateOb, {merge: true});
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work – it sets a property whose key is `some.nested.property` instead.  Inconsistent, but okay.

Fortunately, it appears that `set(updateObj, {merge: true})` does a deep merge, so if you construct your update object as a fully nested object, your nested objects will also be properly merged:

```js
// create the object
db.doc('testCollection/doc').set({p1: {['p2']: {p3: true}}}, {merge: true})
// update the existing object
db.doc('testCollection/doc').set({p1: {['p2']: {p4: true}}}, {merge: true})

// result is now this:
{ p1: { p2: { p4: true, p3: true } } }
```

Comment: Wat. When did they ninja in that? I'm sure it wasn't always like that. It used to do a shallow merge IIRC. But hey, it extremely useful, so thanks for writing about it! 

Comment: You made my day man, I was having the same issue for a long time 

Comment: Wow.  I had no clue this worked.  Very nice.  Wish it was documented somewhere.

Comment: Thanks, undefined, I was struggling with this one.

Answer (score 3):

You can update specific fields of variable(ly) named nested objects like below.

```
ref.set({
    name: "Frank",
    favorites: { food: "Pizza", quantity: 2 }
});

//now the relevant update code
var name = "favorites";
var qty = 111;
var update = {};
update[name+".quantity"] = qty;
ref.update(update);
```

https://jsbin.com/hihifedizu/edit?js,console

Comment: This is the most useful answer for general use. Thanks for helping me out.

Answer (score 2):

2022 Update with Webversion 9 (modular):

```
const docRef = doc(db, 'users', frank); 

var usersUpdate = {};
usersUpdate[`favorites.${key}.color`] = true;

updateDoc(docRef, userUpdate);
```

Comment: this is the modern answer guys

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
var auxKey = "history." + someVar;
var dataToUpdate = {
   [auxKey]: "new data generated"
};
db.collection("users").doc("frank").update(dataToUpdate);
```

Comment: result: {"history": {"valueOfSomeVar": "new data generated"}}

Answer (score -1):

I felt this is the simplest solutions of all the above :)

```js
db.collection("users").doc("frank").update({
    [`favorites.${KEY}.color`]: true
});
```