# Firestore fetch data from inner array of the doc

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, ionic3, google-cloud-firestore

I know how to query simple collection/doc like so:

```
const querySnapshot = await 
this.authenticationProvider.firestoreDb.collection("members").where("userId", 
"==", this.authenticationProvider.user.uid).get();
```

But could I fetch the data from an inner array using a condition on `firestore`?
You can see that where I need to check the `projects/memberList` array and after that need to search the `email`. Could I do that?

[image]

Comment: you cant query a document apparently https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/firestore/documents.md#querying

Comment: Good place to put a gif :) . You can deep down the array using a dot `.` check this [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/arrays). But you have a dynamic list which increments. even though you dynamically query your data there is no way to `index` it and firestore throw error.

Comment: Actually, I need to retrieve the whole doc. But I need to give a search condition after 2 arrays there `projects/memberList` and after `email`. still, I need to retrieve the collection. Could I? @SurajRao

Comment: Here the problem is how can I give the search criteria there due to 2 arrays? @SurajRao

Comment: I don't think you can do that. You can fetch the document and then use TypeScript to filter out the ones you don't need.

Comment: Yes, It seems I have to construct my arrays using this trick explained here no? https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/arrays Thanks @javebratt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that with an array. You will want to structure your data as an object, where each key is the `userId`. Firestore will index the object keys allowing you to run queries against them. Your data strucuture might look like:

[image: firestore]

Then you can run a query like this:

```
const userId = this.authenticationProvider.user.uid
ref.collection('members').where(`memberList.${userId}`, '==', true)
```

You can even embed additional data under each userId key (such as another object), then get all the documents of which that user is a member like so:

```
ref.orderBy(`memberList.${userId}`)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This is awesome :)

Comment: This is great - would there be a way of updating the membersList dynamically, or does it have to be done with a transaction? Something like: `db.collection('members').doc('id).update({ 'memberList.${userId}' : true })`

Comment: I've come across the solution to my comment: [Cloud Firestore: Update fields in nested objects with dynamic key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47295541/cloud-firestore-update-fields-in-nested-objects-with-dynamic-key)