# Insert and merge a particular field in firestore firebase

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a doc in my collection in this format

```
name: xyz,
email: xyz@email.com,
age: 30,
address: {
    street_no: {
        complete_address: somedata,
        pincode: somepin
    },
    city:somecity,
    state:somestate,
    landmark:nearby
}
```

And inside this doc I am trying to insert and merge the `complete_address` with the previous record. To achieve that I am trying this

```
const database = firebase.firestore();
var dataRef = database.collection('collection');
var query = dataRef.doc(key+"").get().then(doc=>{
    if(!doc.exists){
        res.send("doesn't exist");
    }else{
        //few checks
        if(doc.data().accessid != accessid){
            res.send("accessid doesn't match")
        }
        //here I am trying to insert and merge with the previous data
        var form_path = 'address.street_no.complete_address';
        dataRef.doc(key+"."+form_path).set({
            another_address
        }, {merge: true});
    }
}).catch(err=>{
    console.log(err)
})
```

But when I execute this it just add another document in a collection followed by this path `key.address.street_no.complete_address`.

What can I do to only insert and merge with the previous `complete_address` ?

There is `.` instead of `/` in `form_path` because got few ideas from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47295541/cloud-firestore-update-fields-in-nested-objects-with-dynamic-key)

Answer (score 2):

I believe your issue lies within the next couple of lines starting at

`var form_path = 'address.street_no.complete_address';`

Next, You're using `dataRef.doc(key+"."+form_path)`

which means the only document being set is

`/addressCollection/key.{addressCollectionId}`

and `addressCollectionId` being `address.street_no.complete_address`

Instead what you want to do is access the property within the document using dot notation like so.

```
address: {
    street_no: {
        complete_address
```

Example.

```
someDocument.update({
    "address.street_no.complete_address": "some_data"
});
```

Note that "some_data" will replace what ever data is currently stored. You'll want to do one read and merge the data. For example.

```
  const anotherAddress = { address: "123 Fake Street" };

  const document = firebase
    .firestore()
    .collection("addressCollection")
    .doc("someAddressId");

  document
    .get()
    .then(snap => {
      const data = snap.data();
      const completeAddress = data.address.street_no.complete_address };

      // We're using the spread operator here to combine the current completeAddress with anotherAddress
      return { completeAddress, ...anotherAddress };
    })
    .then(newCompleteAddress =>
      document.update({
        "address.street_no.complete_address": newCompleteAddress
      })
    );
```

Comment: Thank you Philip, for you time and your effort. I have solved this problem in another way. Below is my answer

Comment: Thank you. You answer helped me very much!

Answer (score 0):

I got this working.

So I figured out what I was trying to do earlier will create another document in a collection with data respect to it. So I start treated everything as an object and passed an object data to `set()` method.

```
const database = firebase.firestore();
var dataRef = database.collection('collection');
var query = dataRef.doc(key+"").get().then(doc=>{
    if(!doc.exists){
        res.send("doesn't exist");
    }else{
        //few checks
        if(doc.data().accessid != accessid){
            res.send("accessid doesn't match")
        }
        //here I am trying to insert and merge with the previous data
        var mergeData = {
            address : {
            }
        }
        var new_address = {
            key: "address_data"
        }
        mergeData.address[street_no] = {complete_address : address}
        if(dataRef.doc(key+"").set(mergeData, {merge: true})){
            res.send("done")
        }else{
            res.send("failed")
        }
    }
}).catch(err=>{
    console.log(err)
})
```