# updating Map values in array flutter Firebase

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

here is the map and the vlaue im trying to update
[image]

the problem is when i try to update the imageUrl , the whole Map replacing with only ImageUrl new value
like this
[image]

what i want is to update imageUrl only , not effecting other data

this is what i do but not work

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('oorders').doc('MyDocId')
                                 .update({ 'items.0.imageUrl'    :  'new image Url' });
```

Comment: Maybe this can help you [Cloud Firestore: Update fields in nested objects with dynamic key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47295541/cloud-firestore-update-fields-in-nested-objects-with-dynamic-key)?

Comment: I already use dot notation but its effect the other values and delete them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the provided Firestore Database structure it is clear that you are trying to update an element inside an array field in a Firestore document. But currently Firestore doesn't have the ability to update an existing element in an indexed array. It supports only two methods, `arrayUnion()` to add an element and `arrayRemove()` to remove an element from the array as mentioned in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array).

So if you try to do something like the following -

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('oorders')
    .doc('MyDocId')
    .update({'items.0.imageUrl': 'new image Url'});
```

it will delete the array element `items` and create another map named `items` with the field mentioned in the update statement.

As an alternative, you can read the entire array out of the document, make modifications to it in memory, then update the modified array field entirely. This is an error prone and tedious process. You can have a look at this [article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-update-an-array-of-objects-in-firestore-cdb611a56073) to know more about it.

I am not sure of your use case, but it seems you can make your database structure more suitable by using maps(nested objects) instead of arrays. Something like this -

[image]

By doing this you can update the nested objects by dot notation as mentioned [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_fields_in_nested_objects) which will update only the mentioned field without deleting the other fields. The sample to update the document will look like this -

```
   var item = 'item1';
   var propertyToBeUpdated = 'imageUrl';
   var newImageUrl = 'New image Url';
   FirebaseFirestore.instance
       .collection('collectionId')
       .doc('documentId')
       .update({'items.$item.$propertyToBeUpdated': newImageUrl});
```

Comment: _ make modifications to it in memory, then update the modified array field entirely._

this is make seance to do 
but i really care about firebase read and write limit , so im trying to do this with .update 
to not use extra data  

btw this is my fun to post a items 
'List<Map<String,String>> selectedImages = [    ];'
firebaseFirestore
                        .collection('Orders')
                        .doc(orderId)
                        .set({
                      'id': orderId,
                      'items': selectedImages,})

how can i do the structure you mention above

Comment: It seems a different question from the original one. I would suggest you post a new question for this.